# Can きっと be used as for sure?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Can きっと be used as “for sure” as in..

> きっとこの状態でみんなは毎晩家でゆっくりお酒を飲んでいますね。
>   For sure in these circumstances everybody’s drinking every night in their house.

If the grammar is wrong please let me know and feel free to provide alternative correct sentences.

Answer (score 1):

"(That's) for sure" is good translation for「きっと」.

「きっと」explains "it is natural~", "it is certain~", "I'm pretty sure~", etc.

From [goo辞書](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8/#jn-52960)

> - 話し手の決意や確信、また強い要望などを表す。確かに。必ず。「明日は―雨だろう」「―来てくださいね」

So, whatever the phrase explains "certainty" is appropriate.

"***(For sure/True/Definitely), I believe everyone enjoy dining at home in these circumstances.***"